# In SQL Server would misc pages be pushed out when an object grows within a mixed extent?

Tags: sql-server, database-design, data-pages, physical-design

In SQL Server 2008-2012, objects (including tables) are first put in a mixed extent. An extent can accommodate up to 8 pages and accommodates more than one type of page (meaning: pages from more than one object). Say ExtentA has pages from objects A(2), B(2) and C(4) - numbers in parentheses indicate how many pages they own within that extent. Object B grows, and my question is: Would SQL Server start kicking out A and C's pages before assigning B a new, uniform extent (assuming it eventually outgrows extentA) OR it just jumps to a new extent given extentA is already full.

This question was moved from Stack Overflow to DBA. Comments on the [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29371054/in-sql-server-would-misc-pages-be-pushed-out-when-an-object-grows-within-a-mixed):

> Valid question, but why do you ask? Seems to be totally unimportant knowledge. –  usr
>
> Hi, Thanks for the reply. I'm actually in a very difficult database optimization situation in which I have to crack down on unnecessary spaces being allocated for numerous tables (1000+ tables). So I'm starting from the basics... I couldn't figure out this question because I had no means of tracking it.. I can see that a new extent is being assigned, but I cannot find out whether the previous extent was fully used... –  LearnByReading

Comment: If Object B grows it will get allocated 6 more pages in other, different, mixed extents. Then when the ninth page was needed a uniform statement will be allocated. I can't imagine there is much milage in trying to "optimise" this aspect either though. Even if your 1,000 objects were all one page and occupying full extents such that 7/8 pages in each were unused you would only be wasting 55MB

Answer (score 1):

It just jumps to a new, uniform extent.  There is no mechanism to try to convert the first mixed extent into individual uniform extents.

If I understand correctly, when the mixed extent has no data in it any longer, it will switch that extent to being unused.  Then it could be used for either a mixed extent or a uniform extent.